# Is there anything wrong with my put request?

Tags: node.js, axios, request, put

I don't know why this code doesnt update my database

```
app.put('/todos/:id',async(req,res) =>{
try{

    const {id} = req.params; //WHERE değiştiilicek yer
    const { description } = req.body;// SET belirlenecek açıklama
    
    // $1 = desc $2 = id
    const updateTodo = pool.query("UPDATE todo SET description = $1 WHERE id = $2"[description,id]);

    res.json("Todo was updated!")

}
catch(err){
    console.error(error.message);
}
```

})

`axios .put('http://localhost:5000/todos/2',{ description : 'Buy the kite' },config) .then(res => { console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`) console.log(res) }) .catch(error => { console.error(error) });`

Comment: why there's no coma between sql and `[description, id]`? isn't it supposed to?

Comment: thank you for the fix but that still didn't change the db